not loading .env variables inside .ts file with dotenv
I'm trying to load a variable from the .env file inside my generate-keypair.ts file. I'm using dotenv to load the environment variables and esrun to run the TypeScript file. Both my .env file and TypeScript file are in the same directory.
But it keeps giving me this error:
node:internal/process/esm_loader:34
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'F:\web3-solana\generate-keypair\node_modules\.bin\node_modules\dotenv\config.js' imported from F:\web3-solana\gen F:\web3-solana\generate-keypair\node_modules\.bin\esrun-1723725354847.tmp.mjs
Did you mean to import "../dotenv/config.js"?
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:265:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:933:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1157:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  url: 'file:///F:/web3-solana/generate-keypair/node_modules/.bin/node_modules/dotenv/config.js'
}

Node.js v20.12.1

Here's my generate-keypair.ts file:
import 'dotenv/config';
import {getKeypairFromEnvironment} from '@solana-developers/helpers';

console.log(process.env.SECRET_KEY);

const keypair = getKeypairFromEnvironment('SECRET_KEY');

console.log(`✅ Finished! We've loaded our secret key securely, using an env file!`);

When I comment the import "dotenv/config" the code runs without error but gives undefined for the process.env.SECRET_KEY variable.
How can I read the exact value of the SECRET_KEY variable from the .env file instead of undefined?

Please add error messages as text and not as image

Looks like others have the exact same issue: https://github.com/digital-loukoum/esrun/issues/45

Since you are using node.js, you probably have a typescript moduleResolution compiler option of node16 or nodenext, so when you ES modules (import) you have to specify the module path by adding .js extension after file name, in your case you have to import like this: import 'dotenv/config.js'.
If you read the error you should notice that the error provides the solution.

Tried that, still gives the same error : Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]:
